No Jetty ServletContextHandler, Jetty WebSocket SCI unavailable with jetty version 12.0.14
im getting No Jetty ServletContextHandler, Jetty WebSocket SCI unavailable error for the application which uses spring-boot3, jetty12.0.14(ee10)
here detailed logs:
2024-11-15 11:35:52.572:INFO :oejshC.junbiki_1_4_71_2_10_jbk:main: Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2024-11-15 11:36:28.158:WARN :oejew.WebAppContext:main: Failed startup of context oeje10w.WebAppContext@797b0699{junbiki-1.4.71.2.10-jbk,/junbiki,b=[file:///opt/apps/junbiki/work/jetty-0_0_0_0-15700-junbiki-1_4_71_2_10-jbk_war-_junbiki-any-/webapp/, jar:file:///opt/apps/junbiki/work/jetty-0_0_0_0-15700-junbiki-1_4_71_2_10-jbk_war-_junbiki-any-/webapp/WEB-INF/lib/stomp-websocket-2.3.3.jar!/META-INF/resources/],a=STOPPED,h=oeje10s.SessionHandler@404bbcbd{STOPPED}}{/opt/apps/junbiki/webapps/junbiki-1.4.71.2.10-jbk.war}
java.lang.IllegalStateException: No Jetty ServletContextHandler, Jetty WebSocket SCI unavailable
    at org.eclipse.jetty.ee10.servlet.ServletContextHandler.getServletContextHandler(ServletContextHandler.java:177)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.ee10.websocket.server.config.JettyWebSocketServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(JettyWebSocketServletContainerInitializer.java:99)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.ee10.servlet.ServletContainerInitializerHolder.doStart(ServletContainerInitializerHolder.java:155)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:93)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:169)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:113)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.ee10.servlet.ServletContextHandler$ServletContainerInitializerStarter.doStart(ServletContextHandler.java:3050)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:93)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.ee10.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:1294)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.ee10.webapp.WebAppContext.startWebapp(WebAppContext.java:1346)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.ee10.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1304)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.ee10.servlet.ServletContextHandler.lambda$doStart$0(ServletContextHandler.java:1047)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler$ScopedContext.call(ContextHandler.java:1452)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.ee10.servlet.ServletContextHandler.doStart(ServletContextHandler.java:1044)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.ee10.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:503)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:93)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:169)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:120)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Handler$Abstract.doStart(Handler.java:491)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:93)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:169)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:120)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Handler$Abstract.doStart(Handler.java:491)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.gzip.GzipHandler.doStart(GzipHandler.java:118)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:93)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:169)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.start(Server.java:641)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:120)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Handler$Abstract.doStart(Handler.java:491)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:582)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:93)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration.main(XmlConfiguration.java:2033)
2024-11-15 11:36:28.186:INFO :oejsh.ContextHandler:main: Started oeje10w.WebAppContext@4f704591{cargocpc,/cargocpc,b=file:///opt/apps/junbiki/work/jetty-0_0_0_0-15700-cargocpc_war-_cargocpc-any-/webapp/,a=AVAILABLE,h=oeje10s.SessionHandler@4e33a209{STARTED}}{./webapps/cargocpc.war}
2024-11-15 11:36:28.200:INFO :oejes.ServletContextHandler:main: Started oeje10w.WebAppContext@4f704591{cargocpc,/cargocpc,b=file:///opt/apps/junbiki/work/jetty-0_0_0_0-15700-cargocpc_war-_cargocpc-any-/webapp/,a=AVAILABLE,h=oeje10s.SessionHandler@4e33a209{STARTED}}{./webapps/cargocpc.war}
2024-11-15 11:36:28.254:INFO :oejj.ConnectorServer:main: JMX URL: service:jmx:rmi://localhost:15750/jndi/rmi://lxtkj2ed03.common.eu.corp.toyota.com:15750/jmxrmi
2024-11-15 11:36:28.258:INFO :oejs.RequestLogWriter:main: Opened /opt/apps_logs/junbiki/logs/request-2024_11_15.log
2024-11-15 11:36:28.264:INFO :oejj.MetaData:main: Getter/setter type mismatch for mbean attribute formEncodedMethods in class org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConfiguration, attribute will be read-only
2024-11-15 11:36:28.271:INFO :oejs.AbstractConnector:main: Started ServerConnector@36d585c{HTTP/1.1, (http/1.1)}{0.0.0.0:15700}
2024-11-15 11:36:28.272:INFO :oejs.Server:main: Started oejs.Server@4c39bec8{STARTING}[12.0.14,sto=5000] @40554ms

Related codes:
pom.xml :
<packaging>war</packaging>

<plugin>
                        <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty.ee10</groupId>
                        <artifactId>jetty-ee10-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>${jetty.version}</version>
                        <configuration>
                            <testClassesDirectory>${project.basedir}/target/resources</testClassesDirectory>
                            <contextXml>${project.build.outputDirectory}/jetty-web.xml</contextXml>
                            <httpConnector>
                                <port>15700</port>
                            </httpConnector>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>

<dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty.ee10.websocket</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-ee10-websocket-jetty-server</artifactId>
            <version>${jetty.version}</version>
        </dependency>

 <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jetty</artifactId>
        </dependency>

 <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-websocket</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>stomp-websocket</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.3</version>
        </dependency>



jetty-web.xml
<?xml version="1.0"  encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<!DOCTYPE Configure PUBLIC "-//Jetty//Configure//EN" "http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/configure.dtd">

<Configure class="org.eclipse.jetty.ee10.webapp.WebAppContext">

    <Set name="contextPath">/${deployable.artifactId}</Set>

    <Set name="war">
        <SystemProperty name="config.home" default="."/>/webapps/${deployable.artifactId}-${project.version}.war
    </Set>

    <!--Allow log4j & other properties to be loaded outside of the WAR depending on environment-->
    <Set name="extraClasspath">
        <SystemProperty name="config.home" default="default"/>/resources/${deployable.artifactId}
    </Set>
    <!--Note: Issue JETTY-1203 means that we cannot use extraClasspath from WITHIN the WAR file-->
</Configure>

WebSocketConfig.java
package com.toyota.tme.junbiki.config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.messaging.simp.config.MessageBrokerRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.socket.config.annotation.EnableWebSocketMessageBroker;
import org.springframework.web.socket.config.annotation.StompEndpointRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.socket.config.annotation.WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketConfig implements WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {
    @Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry config) {
        //topic adinda kanal acar. Frontend tarafinda bu kanal subscribe edilir
        config.enableSimpleBroker("/topic");
        //client tarafindan bir mesaj gelirse controllerda bunlari kontrol etmek icin yazilir. Biz tek tarafli yayin yaptigimiz icin buna gerek yok
        //config.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");
    }

    @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
        //api yolu belirledigimiz gibi burda da websocket icin yolu belirledik. Ex: localhost:8080/junseq-websocket
        registry.addEndpoint("/jbkseq-websocket").setAllowedOrigins("*").withSockJS();
    }
}


Could you please help with this situation?
I tried configuring jetty-web.xml, but it didn't work. Additionally, I couldn't find sufficient resources to handle this situation, especially for the latest version of Jetty.
I attempted to solve it programmatically using this source: text
